# Pytest unit creation issue to test Server - Client socket apps

Tags: python, sockets, pytest

I have a Python server and client application that is working normally, but for learning purposes, I tried to create a `Pytest` unit test and generate a coverage XML file using `pytest-co`v. However, when testing the server application, it just show collecting for a long period and nothing happens.
Note: `pytest` works with another simple Python code.

Is my test file incorrect?

**SERVER.py**

```
import socket
import threading


def handle_client(client_socket):
    while True:
        # Receive data from the client
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break

        # Convert received data to dictionary
        received_dict = eval(data.decode())
        print("Received dictionary:", received_dict)

        # Process the received dictionary

        # Send response back to the client
        response_dict = {"response": "Data received successfully"}
        client_socket.send(str(response_dict).encode())

    # Close the client socket
    client_socket.close()


def start_server():
    # Create a socket object
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Bind the socket to a specific address and port
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 8888))

    # Listen for incoming connections
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print("Server started. Listening on localhost:8888")

    while True:
        # Accept a client connection
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        print("Connected with", addr)

        # Create a new thread to handle the client
        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()


# Start the server
start_server()
```

**test_server.py**

```
import pytest
from SERVER import handle_client, start_server

@pytest.mark.parametrize("data, expected_response", [
    ({"name": "John"}, {"response": "Data received successfully"}),
    # Add more test cases as needed
])
def test_handle_client(data, expected_response):
    # Create a test client socket
    class TestClientSocket:
        def __init__(self):
            self.received_data = str(data).encode()
        
        def recv(self, buffer_size):
            return self.received_data
        
        def send(self, data):
            response_dict = eval(data.decode())
            assert response_dict == expected_response
    
        def close(self):
            pass

    # Call the function to be tested
    handle_client(TestClientSocket())
    
def test_start_server(mocker):
    # Create a test server socket
    class TestServerSocket:
        def __init__(self):
            self.accept_called = False

        def bind(self, address):
            pass

        def listen(self, backlog):
            pass

        def accept(self):
            self.accept_called = True
            client_socket = TestClientSocket()
            return client_socket, ('localhost', 8888)
    
    # Mock the socket object to return the test server socket
    mocker.patch('socket.socket', return_value=TestServerSocket())

    # Call the function to be tested
    start_server()

    # Assert the expected behavior
    assert TestServerSocket().accept_called == True  # The accept() method should be called
```

**WINDOWS CONSOLE**

COMMAND: pytest -v --cov=test_server --cov-report=xml

```
SCREEN: 
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.13, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: E:\MEGA\0. SYNC\PROJECTS\PYTHON\SOCKET\tests
plugins: anyio-3.6.2, dash-2.9.1, cov-4.1.0, typeguard-2.13.3
collecting ...
```

I tried to simplify the code and use `pytest -v` command but still nothing changed.

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that there's an infinite loop in `test_handle_client()`.  `handle_client()` repeatedly calls `socket.recv()` until that function returns a falsy value, but for the test you provide a "socket" with a `recv()` method that always returns a truthy value.  So `handle_client()` will never finished "receiving" all the data.

I didn't look carefully at `test_start_server()`, but it's possible that a similar issue is present there, too.

---

Since you mention that you're learning pytest, I'll comment that I don't think that this amount of mocking is a good way to write tests:

- The mock sockets behave so differently from real sockets that even if the tests passed, you couldn't be confident that the actual application would work.  You're actually already kind-of experiencing this disconnect, since the application works and the tests don't.
- The mock sockets are very tightly coupled to your specific implementation.  What if you decided that you'd rather use `socket.recvfrom()` instead of `socket.recv()`?  Or implement the server using a third-party networking library instead of raw sockets?  You'd have to rewrite the tests as well.

Here's what I'd recommend doing instead:

- To test that the correct responses are generated for each request, move this logic to it's own function.  Since this new function won't involve sockets at all, and it's inputs and outputs will all be simple strings, it should be pretty easy to test.
- To test that the client and server can successfully communicate with each other, run a client and a server in different threads within the same test function.  This way you can actually send a few messages back and forth, without any mocking.

Here's an [article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/mocking-is-a-code-smell-944a70c90a6a) that goes into more detail about why mocking usually a sign that something's wrong.